# In need of a plugin that can transform text inside a textarea into code-like text

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

Hey guys I'm developing a website so people can paste code in.
But I need some plugin so that the text in the textarea can look like code.

And has **line counter**. (very necessary)
Please recommend something ?

I need something like this 
`1 line
2 line
3 line
4 line
5 line`

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hi! Please note that open-ended library recommendations are specifically off-topic, see the [Tour].

Comment: ah man sorry.. i don't know who to ask :p i really am in a hurry i need something to work with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [codemirror?](http://codemirror.net/)

It can be customized for almost any language. Simple example below

```js
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(myTextarea, {
    lineNumbers: true
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.32.0/codemirror.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.32.0/codemirror.js"></script>

<textarea id="myTextarea">
  var x, y, z;
  x = 5;
  y = 6;
  z = x + y;  
</textarea>
```